# Prevent page reload on form submit

Tags: javascript, html, get

I am trying to submit a form using get method but I dont want the form to refresh or rather when it reloads I want to maintain the data. There seems to be lot of questions on similar lines but none that I tried helped. I am posting my code here:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function formSubmit()
 {
     document.getElementById('form1').submit();
     return false;
 }
</script>


<form id = "form1" method = "GET">
    <br> Query:  <input name="query" id="query" type="text" size="50" value="">
   <input type="button" name="search" value="Get News" onclick = "formSubmit()">
</form>
```

I am using python on the server side.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement:

```
    I am trying to submit a form using get method but I dont want the form  to 
refresh or rather when it reloads I want to maintain the data.
```

Implies to me that your end goal requires AJAX or at least some passing of data to the server and back.  You will not be able to retain scope within Javascript over a page refresh without the use of something like cookies or passing data to/from the server.  Having said that these are more akin to secondary storage mechanisms while you want to retain scope (or primary storage).  To do this I would recommend AJAX.

Comment: Oh I see !! Thanks .. and all the while I thought I was missing something (since it has been quite a while since I have coded a web page). So bottom line is I will need to pass the data back from the server or maintain a cookie about the present state ? Or ofcourse use AJAX as suggested

Comment: @AjayNair I would recommend using AJAX over cookies or passing data back and forth.  If you truly do not desire a complete page refresh AJAX is the way to go.

Comment: Got it. This should server the purpose. !